# How do I redirect to a certain page if there is no database for the website??? IIS, ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, iis-7, sitecore

I have a website in IIS.

That is a sitecore website. So it has `core`, `master` and `web` databases.

Now I want to stop all databases for about 2 or 3 hours for some reasons.

I do not want to stop the website.

Instead, I want to redirect all requests to a certain page.

So, I created a page in its root directory called `Error_Page.html`.

In web.config,

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error_Page.html" />
```

I add this.

I also turn on `HTTP Redirect` feature.

And point to that page for all requests.

But when I type in the website, it is giving me the error that it cannot connect to `core` database.

I know that for `sitecore` to work, it needs `core` database.

I want to know is there anyway for me to change so that, it will redirect to that page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a page called `App_Offline.htm` to the root of the application, and the contents of that page will be served for all requests until you remove/rename it.

See here for more information: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

Comment: Oh.. That works.. Tkz.. But I can't leave that page there.. I need to manually rename it.. when the database is working.. is there any other way that automatically detect the error?? Of coz, i will use this way as the last resort. Tkz a lot...

Answer (score 1):

The customErrors tag you have mentioned is having valid values (provided the page `Error_Page.html` exists).

Since this isn't working for you, you can put in a error handling code in **`Global.asax`** file and handle the SqlException there.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some error logging here ....

    // use Server.ClearError to stop the error from bubbling to the web.config
    Server.ClearError();

    // Redirect to the generic error hanlding page of your choice.
    Response.Redirect("~/Error_Page.html");
}
```

Comment: working for minor error. But not working for major error like Database is down.. and etc..